# Mapping from IDictionary<string, string> to protobuf map<string, string>

Tags: c#, dictionary, protocol-buffers, automapper

I am trying map from `IDictionary<string, string>` to repeated list of google protobuf `map<string, string>`, but it is not happening. I wasn't sure what I am doing wrong. can someone shed some light on this issue, please?

```cs
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public IDictionary<string,string> FieldValues { get; set; }
}
```

//Protobuf

```cs
message TestModelGRPC
{
    int32 id = 1;
    repeated FieldValue field_values = 2;
    message FieldValue {
        map<string, string> values = 1;
    }
}
```

Error Message -

> Mapping types: TestModel -> TestModelGRPC
> ABC.ProductService.Domain.Model.TestModel ->
> ABC.ProductService.Grpc.TestModelGRPC
>
> Type Map configuration: TestModel -> TestModelGRPC
> ABC.ProductService.Domain.Model.TestModel ->
> ABC.ProductService.Grpc.TestModelGRPC
>
> Destination Member: FieldValues
>
> ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map
> configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: KeyValuePair`2 -> FieldValue System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] ->
> ABC.ProductService.Grpc.TestModelGRPC+Types+FieldValue    at
> lambda_method322(Closure , KeyValuePair`2 , FieldValue ,
> ResolutionContext )    at lambda_method321(Closure , Object ,
> TestModelGRPC, ResolutionContext )    --- End of inner exception stack
> trace ---    at lambda_method321(Closure , Object , TestModelGRPC,
> ResolutionContext )

Comment: The equivalent protobuf model here would be map<string, string> values = 1; directly on the model itself; however, observation: you could use protobuf-net/protobuf-net.
grpc here and just use your primary model, without ever needing the .proto model